# C++ Add Object to Array

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

I need to instansiate an object and add it to an array. This is what I currently have in a method:

```
Row r;
rows[count] = r;
```

The problem here is `r` is on the stack and being removed after the function exits. I quick fix is to make `r` static but that is bad right? What should I do? (Sorry, complete C++ noob).

Edit: Removing the deconstructor for Row fixes the problem.

Comment: do you have new/delete in your class?

Comment: The deconstructor for Row deletes the array and that is what is causing the problem. Trying to add something to an array that has been freed.

Comment: Could you please also describe the problem's symptom?  It's possible that you're misdiagnosing its cause.  (This is easy to do with C++!)

Comment: "Edit: Removing the deconstructor for Row fixes the problem." - no, it doesn't fix the problem, it just makes it differently broken. That destructor was there for a reason, right? To prevent memory leaks. You really, really need to read a C++ tutorial if you want to write C++. It's not a language you can get right by guessing.

Comment: @Steve Jessop, agreed. @Louis particularly needs to bone up on copy construction & assignment.

Comment: Alright alright, I didn't claim to be an expert. I do intend to learn hence asking from with the little knowledge I have. Thanks for the help everyone. My lack of knowledge on construction and assignment is exactly what I'm having problems with. Any good tutorials would be appreciated.

Comment: @Louis: sorry, wasn't meant as an attack. C++ is just quite hard to get into. The C++ Programming Language, by Bjarne Stroustrup, is very good: http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-Special/dp/0201700735/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1284515667&sr=8-1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line `rows[count] = r` *copies* the object `r` to the element at index `count` in the array. After that, it doesn't matter what happens to `r`, the array is unaffected.

[Edit: OK, it matters indirectly what happens to `r` - since the copy is using something that `r` can delete.]

This is surprising if you're used to (for example) Java, where an array element isn't actually an object, it's just a reference to one.

Comment: What doesn't work? Does the class `Row` free anything in its destructor, and if so, does it have an `operator=` which copies whatever that is?

Comment: Yes Row frees an array it holds and there is no operator=.

Comment: The `Row` class is broken - when you copy an object you copy its *pointer*, but that doesn't stop the original deleting the thing that pointer points to. The difficult fix is to implement `operator=` and a copy constructor. The easy fix is to use a `vector` instead of an allocated array, so that there's nothing you need to do in the destructor of `Row`.

Comment: no problem.  Btw, aaa is enough "aaa carp" is my "unicorn" moment.

Comment: @Louis If your class has a non-trivial destructor, it *must* also implement a copy constructor and an assignment operator in order to behave properly. This is called the "Rule of Three" (See: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184401400 ) And it exists precisely to avoid problems like this.

Comment: @aaa: OK, I'll aim to remember. Is there any documentation how the @ syntax actually works to trigger comment notification?

Comment: not sure.  @Potatoswapper said first three characters is enough

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::vector` instead of the array, provided construction of `Row` is not arduous:

```
std::vector<Row> rows;

Row r;
rows.push_back(r);
```

When the vector goes out of scope, the destructor `~Row()` will be called for each entry.

You can access the most recent added entry using either

```
const Row& last = rows.back();
```

or

```
size_t count = rows.size();
const Row& last = rows[count - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you're actually creating it on the stack, and then copying the object to the location rows[count]. Note that if you created rows as an array of Row objects, there already was a Row object at that location, created with the default constructor, that you copied over.

For various reasons, in C++ we try to use the standard library containers like std::vector and std::list. These will expand to handle the new elements you add.